# opendaylight: multiple goto instructions in a single flow rule

Tags: openflow, opendaylight

I am using opendaylight (Carbon) and open VSwitch. I am building an application in java for which I would like to send the packet to multiple GoTo target tables. The following code fragment shows how I am building the instructions:

```
   private static InstructionsBuilder createGoToNextTableInstruction(short idstable, short l2switchTable) {
    // Create an instruction allowing the interaction.

    List<Instruction> instructions = new ArrayList<Instruction>();

    Instruction gotoIdsTableInstruction = new InstructionBuilder()
            .setInstruction(new GoToTableCaseBuilder()
                    .setGoToTable(new GoToTableBuilder().setTableId(idstable).build()).build())
            .setKey(new InstructionKey(getInstructionKey())).setOrder(0).build();

    instructions.add(gotoIdsTableInstruction);

    Instruction gotoL2SwitchInstruction = new InstructionBuilder()
            .setInstruction(new GoToTableCaseBuilder()
                    .setGoToTable(new GoToTableBuilder().setTableId(l2switchTable).build()).build())
            .setKey(new InstructionKey(getInstructionKey())).setOrder(1).build();

    instructions.add(gotoL2SwitchInstruction);
    InstructionsBuilder isb = new InstructionsBuilder();
    isb.setInstruction(instructions);
    return isb;
    }
```

The instructions are used to construct a flow rule as follows:

```
   flowBuilder.setMatch(match).setInstructions(isb.build()).setPriority(30)
            .setBufferId(OFConstants.ANY).setHardTimeout(0).setIdleTimeout(0)
            .setFlags(new FlowModFlags(false, false, false, false, false));
```

I run the application and no exceptions are thrown. However, when I go to list the flow rules at the switch, the flow never got installed. I can successfully install flows on the switch when I have a single GoTo instruction but not when I have multiple GoTo instructions.

My questions are :

1. Is having multiple GoTo targets permitted in openflow and supported on all openflow compliant switches? Specifically, does openvswitch support multiple targets?

I tried the following :

```
 sudo ovs-ofctl -O OpenFlow13 add-flow s1 table=0,in_port=2,actions=goto_table:1,goto_table:2
  ovs-ofctl: instruction goto_table may be specified only once
```

Here is my version:

```
  ovs-ofctl --version
  ovs-ofctl (Open vSwitch) 2.4.1
  Compiled Sep 25 2016 21:59:05
  OpenFlow versions 0x1:0x4
```

Is this an ovs version problem?

2. Is this a place where a group table should be used?

Thanks.

Comment: Apparently openvswitch will not let you have multiple goto targets. How can this be done with a group table?

Comment: This might help https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/38232/forwarding-to-multiple-output-ports-using-sdn
I think it is not possible for groups to output to tables at all, though.

Answer (score 0):

I verified that it is indeed not possible to have multiple GoTo targets in a single flow rule in openflow. Just following up here for the benefit of others.